# Device recognition with Javascript

Tags: javascript, identity, identity-management

What properties we can use to recognize a user device ? , i know UserAgent but it can be same for multiple devices. Any unique property or combination of multiple properties to recognize a device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution such as fingerprintjs2, cf documentation here : https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2

And store the unique ID in a cookie or local store...for recognizing the user later...

There are other solutions for generating uuid, you can see some of them in Github, such https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid or https://github.com/LiosK/UUID.js